# How can I disable drag-copy of text?

Tags: 13.10, text-editor, text

Instead of allowing me to change my selection within a highlighted area with the mouse cursor, it attempts to perform a drag and drop operation with the currently selected text, copying the text to a new location.

I am unable to discover the location of this setting. How to revert it back to a more "classic" behavior, (i.e. clicking and dragging within a highlighted area changes the start and end points of the selection).

Comment: Could it be an Accessibility option? Check if all options in System Settings/Accessibility are off.

Comment: Have you found solution to this problem?

Comment: @krypton nope, it's still annoying me